# Unity 3D sound too low

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine, soundeffect

I'm trying to make my sound effects work as in 3D environment in a 2D platformer game.

The problem is that when I set Spatial Blend option to 3D  on my sound effects it gets really quiet but if I keep it on 2D it will play at the same volume through-out the entire room.

All of the answers to this problem recommend keeping the Spatial Blend option on 2d but I actually want to hear the sound effect at different volume levels depending on where the camera/character is.

Answer (score 0):

May be change curve distance volume?

Comment: Can you give an example image of that ? I  tried playing with the volume curve but It doesn't seems to change ingame

Comment: Selected Volume Rolloff is Custom Rolloff and change position points curve to top and run